# i want to change the "margin-left" of a ul element when i click on an image

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
<html>
<ul>
<li><a href="blocks.html">Blocks</a></li>
<li><a href="tools.html">Tools</a></li>
<li><a href="weapons.html">Weapons</a></li>
<li><a href="Armour.html">Armour</a></li>
<li><a href="Mobs.html">Mobs</a></li>
<li><a href="Food.html">Food</a></li>
</ul>


<img onclick="SomeJavaScriptCode" src="button.png">

</html>
```

Above is a simple naviagtion bar and an image with and incomplete onclick function.

```
<style>
ul
{
list-style-type:none;
margin:auto;
padding:0;
float: left;
height:10%;
width:10%;
margin-left: -999px;
}
</style>
```

Above you can see i moved the UL of the page so i does not effect the rest of my code.

How can i make it so that when the button is clicked on the "margin-left: -999px;" changes to "margin-left: 0px;" or any other value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
<ul id="myul">
...
</ul>

<img onclick="changeMargin()" src="button.png">

<script>
function changeMargin ()
{
    document.getElementById("myul").style.marginLeft="0px";
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

or the jQuery way

```
<ul id="myul">
...
</ul>
<img id="img" src="button.png">

<script>
$(function() {
    $('#img').click(function(){
          $('#myul').css('marginLeft','0px')
    })
});
</script>
```